# No Python Interpreter Configured: When I open project folder in PyCharm using command line

Tags: python, pycharm

I am creating virtual environment using `virtualenv` command.

When I am opening a project folder in PyCharm through command line using below command.

`pycharm "project_folder_path"`

It opens project folder in PyCharm but not loading `interpreter` exist in project folder.
Error: `No python Interpreter Configured for this project`

Is there any solution to load `interpreter` exist in project folder and configure automatically through python script.

Comment: set a virtual env

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the interpreter by going to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Project - your_project` -> `Project Interpreter` and choose the virtual environment that you created.